# Convert From One date format to other gives invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert a date from `18/04/2019 13:17:41` to `18-04-2019 13:17:41` ie from `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` to `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`. I have tried moment js and `Date function ()` but they either return null or invalid date ,where I am wrong here ? Any help will be appreciated

```js
let str="18/04/2019 13:17:41";
let strf=str.replace(/[/]/g,"-");
console.log(strf)
let date=moment(strf,"DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS");
console.log(date)
console.log(new Date("18/04/2019 13:17:41")) // gives null
console.log(new Date("18-04-2019 13:17:41")) // gives null
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `MM` has only one meaning,  month... you have used this for your minutes as well..  should be `mm`

Comment: Try -> `moment("18/04/2019 13:17:41", "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Yes that seems to work ,but why the Date() function gives null? @Keith

Comment: that worked ,@Keith.Thanks

Comment: Please use [`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) _to get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps_ and please note that moment tokens are case sensitive, `SS` is for fractional secons while you have to use lowercase `ss` for seconds, see [parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Look here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  take note of the `note`, about `RFC 2822`.. It's the reason date libs like moment exist..

Answer (score 1):

js [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date) use a `YYYY-MM-DD` format

```js
let str="2019/04/18 13:17:41";

console.log(new Date(str)) // works
```

you can use something like this to convert from `DD/MM/YYYY` to `YYYY/MM/DD`
but the best would be to get the date in the right format from the start

```js
let str="18/04/2019 13:17:41";

str = str.split(" ").map(part => part.split("/").reverse().join("/")).join(" ")

console.log(str)
console.log(new Date(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to convert string of format "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss" to moment date. Which is not supported by momentjs. Here are supported string formats which you can convert to moment date.

```
2013-02-08               # A calendar date part
2013-W06-5               # A week date part
2013-039                 # An ordinal date part

20130208                 # Basic (short) full date
2013W065                 # Basic (short) week, weekday
2013W06                  # Basic (short) week only
2013050                  # Basic (short) ordinal date

2013-02-08T09            # An hour time part separated by a T
2013-02-08 09            # An hour time part separated by a space
2013-02-08 09:30         # An hour and minute time part
2013-02-08 09:30:26      # An hour, minute, and second time part
2013-02-08 09:30:26.123  # An hour, minute, second, and millisecond time part
2013-02-08 24:00:00.000  # hour 24, minute, second, millisecond equal 0 means next day at midnight

20130208T080910,123      # Short date and time up to ms, separated by comma
20130208T080910.123      # Short date and time up to ms
20130208T080910          # Short date and time up to seconds
20130208T0809            # Short date and time up to minutes
20130208T08              # Short date and time, hours only
```